# Request url wikipedia por data

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ola, um grande amigo me fez este codigo, sou bem novato em python :`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2018/2018-04/"

page_html = requests.get(url).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html5lib")

links = [ (url+link['href'])
          for link in soup.find_all('a')
          if "pageviews-" in link['href'] ]

for link in links: print(link)
```

Está listando perfeito os dumps da wikipedia, mas eu preciso que seja listado pela data do arquivo, passo um range de datas e ele me lista os arquivos neste range de datas.

Segue o link da wikipedia
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2018/2018-04/

Alguem pode me ajudar ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: pelo que vejo, as listas são baseadas no mês, queres um range dos meses é isso? Para obteres cada lista de cada mês

Comment: Na verdade elas são por data e hora ...eu preciso pegar por uma data e hora num range que eu passo, por exemplo entre 2018-09-04 12:00 e 2018-09-04 12:59. @miguel coloquei exemplos ali na pergunta

Comment: Verdade, vou tentar ajudar. Estás a usar python3 certo? Mas colocaste python 2.7 nas tags...

Comment: Poxa brigadao mesmo..Sim estou usando 3.0, mas este codigo vai pruma aws lambda function que eu acrediuto que seja somente 2.7. SOu bem novato nisso meeeeeeesmo

Comment: Acabei de checar, lambda functions aceitam python 3.6 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomei a liberdade de usar o requests_html ao invés do BeautifulSoup, mas a lógica pode ser facilmente transferida:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from datetime import datetime
import re

url = "https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2018/2018-04/"
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)

pre = r.html.find('pre', first=True)

data_inicial = datetime(2018, 4, 2)
data_final = datetime(2018, 4, 5)

for link in sorted(pre.links):

    # Tentar isolar número entre dois hífens. Se não conseguir, não é um dos links que queremos
    try:
        date_str = re.search(r"-(\d+)-", link).group(1)
    except AttributeError:
        continue  # Ir pra próxima iteração do for

    # Transformamos o número entre dois hífens em objeto datetime
    data_link = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y%m%d")

    # Printamos o link completo somente se estiver entre as datas inicial e final
    if data_inicial <= data_link <= data_final:
        print(url + link)
```

Se fossemos incluir o horário e listar só as páginas de pageviews, teríamos

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from datetime import datetime
import re

url = "https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2018/2018-04/"
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)

pre = r.html.find('pre', first=True)

data_inicial = datetime(2018, 4, 2, 13, 0) # 02/04/2018, 13:00
data_final = datetime(2018, 4, 5, 9, 0) # 05/04/2018, 9:00

for link in sorted(pre.links):

    # link não inclui a base da url; é algo como `projectviews-20180402-150000`

    # Tentar isolar número entre dois hífens. Se não conseguir, não é um dos links que queremos
    try:
        date_str = re.search(r"-(\d+-\d+)", link).group(1)
        # Regex = encontrar e capturar (parênteses) um ou mais dígitos (\d+) seguidos por hífen e mais um ou mais
        # dígitos. Exemplo - em `pageviews-20180405-220000` é capturada a substring `20180405-220000` (padrão que
        #  está dentro do grupo de captura)
    except AttributeError:
        continue  # Ir pra próxima iteração do for

    # Transformamos o número entre dois hífens em objeto datetime com hora
    data_link = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

    # Printamos o link completo somente se estiver entre as datas inicial e final e se contiver a string "pageviews".
    if data_inicial <= data_link <= data_final and "pageviews" in link:
        print(url + link)
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Pedro

Comment: seu código funcionou legal também..como adiciono somente pageviews ,  hora e minuto na data inicial e final ?

Comment: Tu me matou no regex lol ..

Comment: @LaerteJunior heheh, na verdade o regex ficou mais complicado do que precisava; na verdade podia ser só "-(\d+)-"; quer dizer: encontrar e capturar (parênteses) um ou mais dígitos (\d+) que estejam cercados por hífen. Estou atualizando a resposta pra corrigir isso e dar o exemplo de hora e minuto.

Comment: Muitiiiiiiissssmo Obrigado  !!!!!!!!!

Comment: Por nada! Não esqueça de selecionar uma resposta como correta para marcar a questão como resolvida.

Answer (score 0):

No exemplo abaixo estou utilizando o datetime para exibir apenas os de hoje.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime

url = "https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2018/2018-04/"
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://10.1.101.101:8080',
    'https': 'http://10.1.101.101:8080',
    'ftp': 'http://10.1.101.101:8080',

}

page_html = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html5lib")

links = [ (url+link['href'])

          for link in soup.find_all('a')
          if "pageviews-" in link['href'] 
          and datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d') in link['href']]

for link in links: print(link)
```

Comment: Qual o motivo de listar esses proxies? VPN? Imagino que não vá funcionar pra alguém que não tem a mesma VPN configurada.

Comment: Somente porque em minha rede precisa para acessar a internet.
Pode ser removido sem problemas a quem não há este requisito.

Comment: Show !!!  Vou tentar aqui colocar entre um range de data e hora :)

Comment: Muito Obrigado cara vou tentar aqui passar uma data e hora inicial e data e hora final e trazer somente os que tiverem nesse range

Comment: Pergunta @britodfbr esse script sera rodado de hora em hora. Se eu gerar uma array com toda a hora e minutos da hora passada e colocar no in link['href'] aonde você colocou o datetime.now() seria a melhor solução ? Ou se ate funcionaria ? Me desculpe abusar é que faz 3 dias que estou no python lendo e assistindo cursos :)

Comment: kkk, passo por isto também e o pessoal daqui me ajuda muito. Por isto dedico um tempo para ajudar a quem precisa, para pagar minha divida com o coletivo na comunidade.

verei o que posso fazer...

Comment: @LaerteJunior
substitua a 3ª linha do for por:
**and datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H0000') in link['href']**. Como voce executará de hora em hora, e o padrão aparenta ser HHMMSS, esta alteração irá funcionar.

Comment: Cra furunfou mas ta trazendo da hora corrente..tipo agora 2:15 trouxe o ultimo que era 2:00 ..eu precisaria da 1:00 as 1:59

Comment: Você não executará de hora em hora? as 13:15h traz o das 13:00, as 14:15h traz o das 14:00, 15:15h traz o das 15:00 e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: sim sim vai executar de hora em hora mas precisa listar o da hora passada, porque senão pode haver um arquivo novo no wikipedia vamos dizer as 14:20 o das 14/:00 nao pega e quando rodar as 15:00 (ate rodar o script vamos colocar 15:05)  não vai pegar  tambementendeu ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75741/discussion-between-laerte-junior-and-britodfbr).